# Setting include path for Python binary module builds

Tags: python, c, include-path

I have a Python dependency that I'm installing via *PIP*, and it performs a binary build. I need to give it an include path. Setting "INCLUDE_PATH" doesn't seem to be effective.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If it is the gcc compiler, set either [C_INCLUDE_PATH or CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.1/gcc/Environment-Variables.html#Environment-Variables).